# Why is my package information seemingly not updating?

Tags: updates, update-manager, package-info

Are there no updates for **anything** or has something gone wrong on my computer?

As of recent, I have been getting a red warning triangle in my notification bar:

[image: Red Warning Triangle in my notification bar]

When I go to my update manager, it tells me that I have not updated my package information in 14 days (I have)

[image: Update Manager telling me that I have not updated the package info]

If I update it, many sources are left at 0% with the word "Idle" instead of "Downloaded"

[image: Many Sources left as "Idle"]

And here's running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
jack@jack-HP-Compaq-nc6400-EH522AV:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jack: 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org precise InRelease                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Ign http://apt.last.fm debian InRelease                                        
Get:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [2,979 B]                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://apt.last.fm debian Release.gpg                                      
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Err http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             

Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Hit http://apt.last.fm debian Release                                          
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Get:4 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                       
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free i386 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://apt.last.fm debian/stable i386 Packages                             
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free i386 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Ign http://apt.last.fm debian/stable TranslationIndex                          
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,237 B]                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free TranslationIndex                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb InRelease                         
Get:7 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [768 B]                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources            
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free TranslationIndex            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_GB          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_GB          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_GB            
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_GB             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://apt.last.fm debian/stable Translation-en_GB                         
Ign http://apt.last.fm debian/stable Translation-en                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                         
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release.gpg                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release                           
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                      
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free Translation-en_GB               
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                      
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                      
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free Translation-en                  
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                          
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                          
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en_GB           
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                          
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en              
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release        
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages               
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/apps TranslationIndex
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex            
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages               
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex            
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/apps Translation-en_GB            
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 5,096 B in 29s (171 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
jack@jack-HP-Compaq-nc6400-EH522AV:~$
```

After I update it, it still tells me that I have not updated the package information in 14 days. What's gone wrong?

Thanks, Jack :)

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an HPnc6400 with Intel Integrated Graphics. Located in the United Kingdom, so I'm using the GB Ubuntu update servers.

Comment: Try the main servers.

Answer (score 2):

I just found [this question on Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/202463). It helped me to solve my problems with Ubuntu. I Hope it'll help someone else as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's easier to just add the missing key.

Running `sudo apt-get update` will bring up an error message that says

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59
```

The error message ends with `NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59`. You just need to get that number an run `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 082CCEDF94558F59`.

Just replace `082CCEDF94558F59` with whatever `apt-get update` says the missing key is.

If this doesn't work, maybe a firewall is blocking your update, check [the Ubuntu apt-key documentation](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/apt-key) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Woah, I didn't see these answers.

Anyway, eventually, I just removed the offending ppa (the Spotify one) and then it started working again. I've given both of the answers upvotes, however.